# React Input Element : Value vs Default Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

When I render an input element within my component if i set the element "value" it become read-only but if i set the value on "defaultValue" it will never update again when i re-update my state.

Here is my code :

```
    import React from "react";
    export default class EditForm extends React.Component {

    editTransaction(event) {

        var transaction = this.props.transaction;

        event.preventDefault();
        var NewTransaction = {
            transactions_data: {
                amount: this.refs.amount.value
            }
        }

        this.props.editTransaction(NewTransaction, transaction.id);
    }

    closeForm() {
        this.props.closeForm();
    }

    render() {
        var {amount}=this.props.transaction;
        return (
            <div>
                <br/>
                <h4>Edit Transaction</h4>
                <div className="btn btn-danger pull-right" onClick={this.closeForm.bind(this)}>close</div>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <form onSubmit={this.editTransaction.bind(this)}>
                    <div>
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input value={amount} onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)} className="form-control"
                               id="amount" name="amount" type="number"
                               ref="amount"/>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input className="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and then i found out if i make an error out of this by adding
`onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)}` on my input element, it works properly ( it updating while the props or state is updating, and i can re-type the value), but i think this is not a proper solution, because it cause errors on my browser console. It is because "this.onChange" function does not exist.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: React treats inputs as either controlled (value bound with prop/state), or uncontrolled (no binding on value). I'd very much recommend reading the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) on this several times over because this can be confusing in the beginning. You mentioned errors in the console, could you update your question with their details as well?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The reason your input doesn't work is because you need to `define` the `onChange` function which actually `sets the state` with the updated value. You can probably do it inline since it only needs on statement like

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.inputVal} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({inputVal: e.target.value})}} />
```

However I would recommend you to use an `onChange` method as you can handle multiple inputs together with it and it looks cleaner

```js
class EditForm extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        
        }
    }
    onChange(e) {
         this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    editTransaction(event) {

        var transaction = this.props.transaction;

        event.preventDefault();
        var NewTransaction = {
            transactions_data: {
                amount: this.refs.amount.value
            }
        }

        this.props.editTransaction(NewTransaction, transaction.id);
    }

    closeForm() {
        this.props.closeForm();
    }

    render() {
       
        return (
            <div>
                <br/>
                <h4>Edit Transaction</h4>
                <div className="btn btn-danger pull-right" onClick={this.closeForm.bind(this)}>close</div>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <form onSubmit={this.editTransaction.bind(this)}>
                    <div>
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input value={this.state.amount} onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)} className="form-control"
                               id="amount" name="amount" type="number"
                               ref="amount"/>
                         <input value={this.state.amount1} onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)} className="form-control"
                               id="amount1" name="amount1" type="number"
                               ref="amount"/>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input className="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EditForm/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, what if i don't want to set state in this component? since i am using REDUX, all states are in my reducer, which loaded on my index.js ( the js file that calls upon this EditForm component). that's why i loaded that value from props, is there any solution that i can call inline function returning error like behavior but does't catch as error in browser console? thank you very much

Comment: Redux best practice is to have the ui state in the local state and not the redux store. However, if you want to use redux store, then you can dispatch an action in the onChange function where I set state and that action will call the reducer to change the state. Ask me if you face any problem

Comment: How would you reset it to the the original value if I have an option of cancel?

Comment: @SaifAliKhan By Reset do you mean whatever the changes you have made revert them back

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes. I am facing this issue that I have set the value at the first time, now I am changing that value through setState on onChange function. Now I also have an option to cancel. How will I get that value which was initially set on cancel? since it is updated with new value?

Comment: @SaifAliKhan While setting the state initially you need to keep a copy of that initial State another state variable

Comment: But if I have to edit lots of fields, then I have to maintain an initial state for all those fields and also I have to maintain a state for changed field. Don't you think this is a bad practice? Can we do it in a better way than this?

Comment: @SaifAliKhan, definitely this is not the best solution, I would say make use of uncontrolled component in that case, and then you can update the input state on save button and reset from reset button

Comment: Initially I've also thought of that. But the problem is If I use defaultValue instead of value that will only load on first render. 
I am having a case where I have a table of users and an update button to update them.
If I click on update button all the information regarding user appears in a model prefilled and I can update them there, If I use defaultValue in place of value the values which are prefilled will be those values which were filled on 1st load of that modal.Because the component already rendered. So I can't use uncontrolled component. Are you getting what I am trying to say?

Comment: maybe you can ask a question yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define an onChange method, if you are using redux that could be an action that updates your component state via a reducer. An easier method using simple state with es6 is shown below. Furthermore, you are getting the value from the input field via `ref` which is discouraged by Facebook. This should also give you an error because you are trying to control and uncontrolled component.

[Here's a link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) to the form documentation for further reading.

```
class Foo extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
      inputVal: '',
    });
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.inputVal);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.inputVal} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, what if i don't want to set state in this component? since i am using REDUX, all states are in my reducer, which loaded on my index.js ( the js file that calls upon this EditForm component). that's why i loaded that value from props, is there any solution that i can call inline function returning error like behavior but does't catch as error in browser console? thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

When you set the value on an input in React, its value will never change (unless you specify an onChange handler)

```
<input type="text" name="address" value="Europe" />
```

The end result of this element is a textbox with the value **Europe** that cannot be changed, so effectively, it's a read-only textbox.

Instead, when you want to provide a default value for your input field, you should use the defaultValue attribute as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="address" defaultValue="Europe" />
```

So just replace the **value** attribute with **defaultValue**

Answer (score 0):

I was tinkering with this and found a really simple solution:

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.enterText = this.enterText.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        userNameText: 'user name',
        pswdText: 'pswd',
        textEntry: false
    }
}

async enterText() {
    if (!this.state.textEntry) {
        await this.clearText()
        this.setState({textEntry: true})
    }
}

clearText() {
    this.setState({
        userNameText: '',
        pswdText: ''
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
                <h1 className="App-title">
                    Welcome
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div className="login-fields">
                <LoginFields userNameText={this.state.userNameText} pswdText={this.state.pswdText} onFocus={this.enterText} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

So, upon initial render(), the state of the fields are whatever is hard coded in the constructor. When the user clicks in either the name or pswd box (these could easily be separated), both are cleared with clearText() and then both are set to null with allowText(). Once set to null, the user input text is accepted.

Make sure the LoginFields component has this in the input:

`onFocus={this.props.onFocus}`