# How to set default variable in JSX for const with selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am fairly experienced with PHP and Wordpress theming, but now struggling with the new Gutenberg editor. I have created a custom block plugin, which involves a lot of JS (React). To the latter I am a bit new.

The block is creating a simple wrapper div with a html lang attribute assigned to it based on the input of a selector. The following code is working fine, however only when the selector is changed. By default the langCode variable remains empty. Any idea what goes wrong?

```
registerBlockType( 'lang-group-block/lang-group', {
    // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
    title: __( 'Language group', 'lang-group-block' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'flag', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
    category: 'layout', // Block category — Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.
    keywords: [
        __( 'Language', 'lang-group-block' ),
        __( 'Group', 'lang-group-block' ),
    ],

    attributes: {
        // Register langCode attribute to save the chosen language
        langCode: {
            type: 'string',         
        },
    },

    edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {
        const {
            langCode = 'en', 
        } = attributes;


        const groupIndicatorStyle = {
            fontSize: 14,
            color: "#ff0000",
            textAlign: "center",
            paddingTop: "40px",
        }

        return (            
            <Fragment>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody
                        title={ __( 'Language', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block' ) }
                        initialOpen={ true }
                    >
                        <SelectControl
                            label={ __( 'Language', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block' ) }                         
                            value={ langCode }
                            options={ [
                                {
                                    value: 'en',
                                    label: __( 'EN', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block' ),
                                },
                                {
                                    value: 'nl',
                                    label: __( 'NL', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block' ),
                                },
                                {
                                    value: 'de',
                                    label: __( 'DE', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block' ),
                                },
                            ] }
                            onChange={ ( selectedOption ) => setAttributes( { langCode: selectedOption } ) }
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
                <div style={ groupIndicatorStyle }>
                    language group: { langCode }
                </div>
                <div
                    className={ className }
                    lang={ langCode }
                >
                    <InnerBlocks />
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );      
    },

    save( { attributes, className } ) {
        const {
            langCode = '',
        } = attributes;

        let classes = className;
        if ( '' == langCode ) {
            { langCode: 'en' }
        }   

        return (
            <div
                className={ classes }
                lang={ langCode }
            >
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Input Element : Value vs Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807901/react-input-element-value-vs-default-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working:

```
save( { attributes, className } ) {
    const { langCode } = attributes;
    let classes = className;

    return (
        <div
            className={ classes }
            lang={ langCode || 'en' }
        >
            <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
    );
},
```

EDIT: Couldn't reproduce the still existing error. So here's the complete block already with createElements. Another suggestion: you're setting using 'en' as default. Why not setting it as such?

```
;( function ( wp ) {

    const el = wp.element.createElement;
    const __ = wp.i18n.__;

    const { Fragment } = wp.element;
    const { InspectorControls , InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
    const { PanelBody , SelectControl } = wp.components;

    wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 'lang-group-block/lang-group', {
        // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
        title: __( 'Language group', 'lang-group-block' ), // Block title.
        icon: 'flag', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
        category: 'layout', // Block category — Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.
        keywords: [
            __( 'Language', 'lang-group-block' ),
            __( 'Group', 'lang-group-block' ),
        ],

        attributes: {
            // Register langCode attribute to save the chosen language
            langCode: {
                type: 'string', 
                default : 'en'       
            },
        },

        edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {

            const groupIndicatorStyle = {
                fontSize: 14,
                color: '#ff0000',
                textAlign: 'center',
                paddingTop: '40px',
            }

            return el( Fragment, null , 
                el( InspectorControls, null,
                  el( PanelBody,
                    { title: __('Language', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block'), initialOpen: true },
                    el(SelectControl, {
                      label: __('Language', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block'),
                      value: attributes.langCode,
                      options: [
                        { value: 'en', label: __('EN', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block') },
                        { value: 'nl', label: __('NL', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block') },
                        { value: 'de', label: __('DE', 'rapp2020-lang-group-block') }
                      ],
                      onChange: function onChange(selectedOption) { return setAttributes({ langCode: selectedOption }); }
                    })
                  )
                ),
                el( 'div', { style: groupIndicatorStyle }, 'language group: ', attributes.langCode  ),
                el( 'div', { className: className, lang: attributes.langCode }, el(InnerBlocks, null) )
              );
        },

        save( { attributes, className } ) {
            return el( 'div', { className: className, lang: attributes.langCode || 'en' }, el(InnerBlocks.Content, null) );
        },
    } );

} )( window.wp );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.

When I use the updated block on a blank page, and do not change the selector, the frontend output is as follows:

`<div class="wp-block-lang-group-block-lang-group" lang="">
<p>test default</p>
</div>`

So the html lang attribute is not set.

Comment: See edit. I couldn't quite reproduce this behaviour. The above code is working well for me. However, I've suggested using the default keyword in the attributes definition as you are in fact using the value en as default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The default keyword worked out (also in the code of your first answer).Can you maybe explain what is the difference of using 'const el = wp.element.createElement;' for the return functions?

Comment: The difference of using el to the 'return <div> ...'? The first one is es5 while the latter is JSX. When your pasting the JSX into babeljs.io you will get something like React.createElement( 'div' , null , 'foobar' ); Wordpress has implemented and somewhat modified that function (I guess) into wp.element.createElement. And const el = ... is a shortcut you see a lot. So, basically, using return el( Fragment , null , ... ); you return the React-compontent Fragment as a wrapper with its children. Did that make sense to you?