# dynamic default value in Text Field of react material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik-material-ui

I'm trying to create a form with two input fields, one is Select, and the other is TextField. I want to dynamically assign a default value to the TextField based on the value of the Select field.

Below is my select form control

```
             <Select
              labelId="existingCompanyName"
              id="existingCompanyName"
              className={classes.myTextFieldRoot}
              name="existingCompanyName"
              label="Existing Company Name"
              variant='outlined'
              onChange={handleSelectChange}
              value={existingCompanyID}
            >
              <MenuItem 
                value="">
                  <em>None</em>
              </MenuItem>
              
              {
                api.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <MenuItem value={item.id}>
                      {item.forwarderCompanyName}
                    </MenuItem>
                  )
                })
              }

            </Select>
```

and this is the Text Field

```
             <TextField
              name="existingCompanyEmail"
              onChange={handleChange}
              variant='outlined'
              className={classes.myTextFieldRoot}
              type="email"
              placeholder={messages['common.companyEmail']}
              label={<IntlMessages id='common.companyEmail'/>}
              defaultValue={forwarderCompanyEmail} 
             />
```

I successfully retrieved the selected value and assigned the value to the component state.
Now using that value which is actually the id. I'm trying to fetch the email associated with that particular id in the array, which again I am able to find it successfully.
On using

```
console.log(forwarderCompanyEmail) // gives the expected email
```

but the same variable when being assigned to the default prop of the TextFiled does not show the default value in my UI.

So, I used another approach and assigned this variable to the component state (useState hook) but that resulted in an even worse situation. My UI hanged saying can't do too many re-renders.

To check whether the defaultValue prop is faulty or something I just passed a string to and to my surprise it shows on the UI. And when I switch back to the variable it again does not show anything, while **console.log(forwarderCompanyEmail)** and **alert(forwarderCompanyEmail)** shows me the desired output each time.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Replace "defaultValue" with "value". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807901/react-input-element-value-vs-default-value

Comment: But then I won't be able to change that. I want a value to be preexisting if the user does not write anything in the TextField and if the user writes something then the default value should get replaced with the even.target.value

Comment: defautValue cannot be controlled. defaultValue only assigns value while rendering for the first time. if what you have assigned a defaultValue that is depended on some async request response, then it won't work. Thats why I suggest to have a controlled one by replacing defaultValue to value. and assign a state variable to it. And then update this state variable using useEffect with dependency of forwarderCompanyEmail.

Comment: Thanks, Tuhin. I truly appreciate your help. I will implement based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

I used like this, you can add dynamic data to the default value of the textfield using backticks and useState

for example:-
const [name,setName] = useState("Rocky")

<TextField
defaultValue={`${name}`}
/>